# How to change tag values on jsp using servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Hello I have a jsp with content like

```
<div id="somediv">Sample text</div>
<img id = "mainPicture" src = "file.jpg" height="1024" width="600"/>
```

and so on. 
Also I have a servlet, that has to handle requests and proceed response, that change jsp content (for example src in mainPicture and text in somediv).

How can I do that? Can I return some hashmap from servlet and handle it in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just insert java code in jsp?

like

"<% java-code %>"

for direct output use "<%= java-code %>"

in your example:

```
<% String sample = "Sample teyt";
   String fileSrc = "file.jpg"; %>
<div id="somediv"><%= sample %></div>
<img id = "mainPicture" src = "<%= fileSrc %>" height="1024" width="600"/>
```

now you just need to edit the Strings in Java when you want to edit the content there

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used jQuery and called there my servlet. Then I edited elements attributes with output data in that jQuery function.